# Increased MTU but still can't send large UDP packets

Tags: sockets, udp, texas-instruments, mtu

a little info on what i'm trying to achieve here first. I'm using a Texas Instrument board EVM6678LE, and what i am trying to do is to increase the UDP transfer rate between the board and my PC.

I've increased the MTU on my PC through netsh>interface>ipv4 to 15,000. But when i ping the board from my PC i am only able to ping up to "ping 192.168.2.100 -l 10194", if i ping with 195bytes onwards i'll receive a request timeout. Is this a limitation of my PC or something?

Does anyone have any idea what could be the possible cause of this? Any advice or suggestions at all would be welcome. As the only way to increase the transfer rate i could think of it increasing the per packet size which reduces overhead. And at 10k i have a rate of around 9.1MB/s, and i'm trying to attain 25MB/s.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the MTU on your PC may not prevent fragmentation. I don't know exactly what is controlling this, but your network card or driver can fragment the packet even when MTU is not reached. Use a sniffer like Wireshark to see how the packets are sent.

About the timeout, it is possible that your board rejects fragmented pings (because of Ping of Death protection). There is also a possibility that its packet buffer is 10kB (10240) bytes long, and can't receive larger packets. Also, make sure that the receiving endpoint have a matching MTU.

Anyway, if you are trying to increase transfer rate, you are on the wrong track. The overhead for UDP is 8 bytes, IP 20 bytes, Ethernet 18 bytes, which make a total of 46 bytes (oh, coincidence, 46+10194 is exactly 10240). 46 bytes overhead for 1024 MTU is 95.5%. 46 bytes for 4096 is 98.9%, 46 bytes for 16384 is 99.7%. That means you gain +3.5% transfer rate from 1024 to 4096 MTU, and another +0.8% from 4096 to 16384. The gain is just ridiculous, and you should just let the MTU to the common default 1500.

Anyway, going from 9.1MB/s to 25MB/s just by changing the MTU is IMPOSSIBLE (if it was, why the PC default is not higher ?). Here I guess you are using Fast Ethernet (100BASE-T), and you are already transferring near full bandwidth. To get higher rates, you would need to have Gigabit Ethernet (1000BASE‑T). That means you need both hardware endpoints to support 1000BASE-T.

Comment: I know it looks rediculous.. I find it weird too. But i'm  told the board supports Gigabit Ethernet and that it should be no problem achieving the rate. I wrote a program to send and receive large udp packets on my pc, and to achieve the rate i want i need to send at around 25-32k bytes.

Comment: As for the fragmented ping. I did use wireshark, i had the fragmented ping issue before i increased the MTU, but after increasing the MTU to 15k, on wireshark it looks fine to me, i am able to see the 11k ping request on wireshark, just that there's not reply coming back in at all.

Comment: @Cherple If the packets are not fragmented, then maybe this has to do with buffer size. Check if you can get/set the buffer on the board. On Windows, you can see the link negotiated speed using `wmic NIC get Name,Speed`. If it isn't 1.000.000.000, then probably one endpoint doesn't support Gigabit. Also, did you actually measured significant speed increase when increasing MTU ? If it is the case, then there is probably something wrong with the UDP program (it would be like you are sending exactly 1 packet every ms, regardless of the size).

Comment: I've read through the documents and increased the buffer size as instructed in the documents. The wmic also shows 1,000,000,000.
As for the speed increase, these is what i got. 2048B - 1.01MB/s, 4096B - 2.01MB/s, 8192B - 4.20MB/s. But why would this be an issue? Shouldn't a gigabit ethernet be able to support sending data of such size easily per millisec? Also, maybe i should mention that my sender has a sleep(1) for every send, so yes i am limiting my program to send one packet per ms, else my receiver will be flooded.

Comment: @Cherple The sleep(1) is the problem. Try to just remove the sleep.  Sockets are by default synchronous, so send() will block a moment when you sent too much, effectively setting the data rate at ~100MB/s. This would be a problem on an internet connection, because it would flood the router and its slower link, but here your other endpoint is on the same link. Note that it may be possible that the driver don't actually wait the transfer, and return after the buffer copy (you'll notice a packet loss). You may also want to limit. In both case, just add multiple send() after each sleep().

Comment: @Cherple Also, you could just let the packets be fragmented. Can you send packets larger than the MTU ? If it doesn't work, maybe fragmentation is disabled ? Did you set the _don't fragment_ option ?